# Does apple allow sound detection when app is in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, background, alarm

In one of my apps I have to detect external sound even if the app is in the background. I have some question on this.

1. Is it possible to detect external sound continuously even if the app is in background mode or closed? If so then will it have an effect on the device battery?
2. Does apple allow these kinds of app?

If my first question is not possible then is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is impossible to detect the external sound when the app is in background.Due to background task time restrictions, iOS Background Task can not be run more than 10 secs.
2. app is not possible.

You can make notifications while the app running in background. But I dont think any way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.But you can make it only for some secs.
 With Push Notifications it is possible.